# App Crashes when button is pressed; iOS Sim

Tags: ios, crash, ios-simulator

I am building/learning my first Xcode app. I've used C before, and am attempting to learn Objective C to build iPhone apps.

I've built a simple app, and when I run the iOS simulator, and press a button which refers to another screen in my storyboard, the app crashes. I've built the entire app thus far using storyboard.

This is my entire main.m file...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

This is the error...

> 2014-03-02 21:22:04.422 Meal Plan Generator[4777:70b] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push
>   segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an
>   instance of UINavigationController.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001018a2795 **exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x00000001015ee991 objc_exception_throw + 43  2   UIKit
>
>   0x00000001006ef051 -[UIStoryboardPushSegue
>   destinationContainmentContext] + 0    3   UIKit
>
>   0x0000000100252096 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 80
>     4   UIKit                               0x0000000100252044
>   -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 17    5   UIKit                               0x0000000100326450 -[UIControl
>   _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 203   6   UIKit                               0x00000001003259c0 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 530   7
>
>   UIKit                               0x0000000100286c15 -[UIWindow
>   _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 701  8   UIKit                               0x0000000100287633 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 988     9   UIKit
>
>   0x0000000100260fa2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 211  10  UIKit
>
>   0x000000010024ed7f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 9549  11 
>   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101831ec1
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17   12  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101831792
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242   13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010184d61f __CFRunLoopRun + 767     14  CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010184cf33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467     15  GraphicsServices
>   0x00000001039923a0 GSEventRunModal + 161  16  UIKit
>   0x0000000100251043 UIApplicationMain + 1010   17  Meal Plan Generator
>   0x0000000100001193 main + 115     18  libdyld.dylib
>   0x0000000101f1a5fd start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: And when you post a question like this, you must always include the complete error message.

Comment: I'm sorry. I will include the error message. Where is it located? Also, @rmaddy I will be reading that! Looks like a quality article!

Comment: @rmaddy I've added the complete error message (I believe).

Answer (score 1):

the error says you are trying to use the push option but your view controller does not have navigation controller. in your storyboard click on the first view that you are trying to push from then from the top menu in the editor section select embed and then select navigation controller. that error will go away. make sure your identifier is set in the storyboard for the segue as well. alternatively select the segue and change it to modal and then try and the app will compile.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your IBAction method is hooked up properly to your .h or .m file. You may have set the action and deleted the method, which would result in the the class being unable to respond to the selector.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand! But I will look!

Comment: @jfrankum Now that you've posted the error, you can ignore this answer. It has nothing to do with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `nextviewcontroller` to hierarchy of controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Select the view controller in Storyboard which has the button and select the 'Editor' menu and choose 'Embed In' and select 'Navigation Controller'.